# Do air compressor quick disconnects seal on both sides?

Tags: tools

I realize the air pressure quick disconnects are self-sealing, but do they seal on both the male and female end ? or is it only one way?

Comment: Would you want your disconnected nailer to have one last shot available from the compressed air trapped in the 50 foot hose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Only the female end self seals.  The male stays open, at least on my cheapo version.

Answer (score 0):

Pressurize it, take it loose and find out (TL;DR: No. ;)

Pro-tip: Kink the hose like you do with garden hoses, and let the air out slowly (pointed away from yourself) when you disconnect a male end. Don't let it 'fire-hose' itself and flail all about, which can damage it or you. However, unlike garden hoses, NEVER put your finger over the end to try and stop the flow of air.

Comment: I'd never risk damaging a hose by kinking it. If you want a soft release, get a safety coupler like the Milton ("Milton S-99705 1/4" FNPT M Style Safety Coupler") or even a Husky from home cheapo.

Comment: Neat, [they](http://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_200320235_200320235) do make these. "Reduces the risk of possible injury or damage due to accidental air line disconnect. Uses double click to engage properly. First click locks coupler and plug; second click engages air pressure. When disconnecting, first click will relieve air pressure; second click allows coupler and plug to be safely disengaged."